# Mismatch error in function that returns minimum in the row of another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a VBA function that reads the 11th row of another worksheet and finds the minimum value on the row.

However, the minimum's absolute value must be less than 100. (The row displays both percentages and regular values and I only need the minimum percentage.)

Here is what I have so far, thanks to the help of answers in a previous question I asked:

```
If (.Cells(11, Colcount).Value < min) And (Abs(.Cells(11, Colcount).Value) <= 100) Then
```

This line is giving me the error:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Furthermore, once I have the value of the minimal value in the 11th row, I want to assign the value of the cell right above to a variable, thanks to the function Worst.

```
Function Loss(worksheet1 As Worksheet) As Double

    Dim min As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myRight As Long, Colcount As Long

    min = 100

    With worksheet1
        myRight = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For Colcount = 4 To myRight
            If (.Cells(11, Colcount).Value < min) And (Abs(.Cells(11, Colcount).Value) <= 100) Then
                min = .Cells(11, Colcount).Value
            End If
        Next Colcount

    End With

    Loss = min

End Function

Function Worst(worksheet1 As Worksheet) As String

    Dim min As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myRight As Long, Colcount As Long



    min = 100

    With worksheet1
     myRight = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

     For Colcount = 4 To myRight

            If (.Cells(11, Colcount).Value < min) And (Abs(.Cells(11, Colcount).Value) <= 100) Then
               min = .Cells(11, Colcount).Value
              Worst = .Cells(10, Colcount).Value
          End If
     Next Colcount
End With


End Function
```

Comment: What is the `.Value` of `.Cells(11, Colcount)`? That should give you a clue.

Comment: the value is a double

Comment: Maybe better said, what is the *specific* value of that cell that throws the error? It's probably not numeric.

Comment: the numeric values in the 11th row start on column D. these are the ones I want to filter out then find the minimum

Comment: Well then `colCount` can't start at `1` right, because it sounds like the value in column A is not numeric? Better yet, add an `IsNumeric` check before attempting that line.

Comment: can I just start Colcount at 4 instead? I am not familiar with the IsNumeric expression

Comment: You could. It's just not robust at all. Here's the [`IsNumeric`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnumeric-function) documentation.

Comment: I tried and now, the error no longer appears however it inly returns a value of 100 for the minimum

Comment: @BigBen I also added a second function to return the value of the cell right above the cell with the minimum value. Would you mind checking it out? Sorry for bugging you but I am very new to VBA and this is way too advanced for me.

Comment: You should make a second question with the issue you're having in the second function.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a `Type Mismatch` if the cell value is not numeric.

Add an additional check using `IsNumeric` before attempting the comparison and `Abs`.

```
Function Loss(worksheet1 As Worksheet) As Double

    Dim min As Double
    min = 100

    Dim myRight As Long
    myRight = worksheet1.Cells(1, worksheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim colCount As Long

    For colCount = 4 To myRight
        With worksheet1.Cells(11, colCount)
            If IsNumeric(.Value) Then
                If .Value < min And Abs(.Value) <= 100 Then
                    min = .Value
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next colCount

    Loss = min
End Function
```